# What are the Creatures?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

*You look all around as the darkness has cleared

And now in your presence you see something weird

Two creatures before you, oh what a strange sight

One man is burning and shines brilliant light

Next to him another you finally see

A woman who melted, though glad as can be*

*The pair may look odd, but they get along well

Though if they were to mix, it'd be all except swell

In spite of their state they will still move around

You may even catch one jump off of the ground

They have other things which to do they sure ought

Sometimes they work gracefully, other times not*

*As working together they finish their task

They walk to the exits, then leave in a flash

You watch them both go as they're finally done

You step back and realize you had some good fun

Lasers and fairies and boxes galore

You think you'll come back, well, at least five times more.*

***Now that I've told this unique tale to you

What are these creatures, and what did you do?***

*Hint 1:*

> You think of the day when the two you did find
> And realize it must have been 2009

*Hint 2:*

> You wonder why any adventure so wild
> Should happen to you, who are likely a child

*Hint 3:*

> If you want to have that adventure today
> Log on a computer, and merely hit play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be:

> The "**[Fireboy and Watergirl](https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-fireboy-and-water-girl-in-the-forest-temple)**" series of online flash games.

*You look all around as the darkness has cleared

And now in your presence you see something weird

Two creatures before you, oh what a strange sight

One man is burning and shines brilliant light

Next to him another you finally see

A woman who melted, though glad as can be*

> The eponymous characters are a male fire elemental (burning and shining), and a female water elemental (who has "melted")

*The pair may look odd, but they get along well

Though if they were to mix, it'd be all except swell

In spite of their state they will still move around

You may even catch one jump off of the ground

They have other things which to do they sure ought

Sometimes they work gracefully, other times not*

> Fire and water shouldn't mix, the characters can move and jump, and should work together to solve the puzzles (though how graceful that is is down to the player!)

*As working together they finish their task

They walk to the exits, then leave in a flash

You watch them both go as they're finally done

You step back and realize you had some good fun

Lasers and fairies and boxes galore

You think you'll come back, well, at least five times more.*

> Again, they work together to solve the puzzles needed to get to the exit of each level. Lasers and boxes feature prominently in the puzzles. I'm not familiar with the later games, but number 6 is subtitled 'Fairy Tales', so I imagine fairies might play a part. There are a total of 6 games in the series at the moment.

Comment: Wonderful job! : )